# What public company form or annual filing is similar to U.S. SEC's 10-K but for the United Kingdom?

Tags: stocks, investing, united-kingdom, annual-report

In the U.S., they use a form called 10-K (http://www.sec.gov/answers/form10k.htm) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_10-K).

Is there a similar form in the UK? What is it called and where might one find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Form 10-K* is the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission's (SEC) name and mandated filing format for an *annual report to shareholders*, codifying the [required parts of the report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_10-K#Parts) that public companies listed on a U.S. exchange must annually disclose and file with the SEC.

In the U.K., similar concerns governing publicly traded companies fall under the UK [Financial Conduct Authority (FCA)](http://www.fca.org.uk/), and the Financial Services Authority (FSA) that came before it. The FCA's handbook has one part on [Disclosure and Transparency Rules](https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk/handbook/DTR/), specifically [DTR 4.1 Annual financial report](https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk/handbook/DTR/4/1.html), which mandates publication of **annual financial reports**. Brief quote:

> **Publication of annual financial reports**
>
> An issuer *[whose transferable securities are admitted to trading and whose home state is the U.K.]* must make public its annual financial report at the latest
>   four months after the end of each financial year.
>
> An issuer must ensure that its annual financial report remains
>   publicly available for at least five years.
>
> **Content of annual financial reports**
>
> The annual financial report must include:
>
> 1. the audited financial statements;
> 2. a management report; and
> 3. responsibility statements.
>
> *[... goes on to describe contents in more detail ...]*

According to [this summary (PDF)](http://www.linklaters.com/pdfs/Insights/corporate/1106TransparencyDirective.pdf), such reports must be published using a *Regulatory Information Service (RIS)* (e.g., an approved news wire service) as well as made available to the public, typically on the company web site. Shareholders may opt to receive a hard copy notification that the information has been published.